# Why does meteor undo changes to collections nested in an observer method?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to implement something like this:

```
/* We use the command pattern to encode actions in
   a 'command' object. This allows us to keep an audit trail
   and is required to support 'undo' in the client app. */
CommandQueue.insert(command);

/* Queuing a command should trigger its execution. We use
   an observer for this. */
CommandQueue
   .find({...})
   .observe({
       added: function(command) {
           /* While executing the action encoded by 'command'
              we usually want to insert objects into other collections. */
           OtherCollection.insert(...)
       }
   });
```

Unfortunately it seems that meteor keeps the prior state of the `OtherCollection` while executing the transaction on `CommandQueue`. Changes are made temporarily to the `OtherCollection`. As soon as the transaction on `CommandQueue` finishes, the prior state of the `OtherCollection` will be restored, though, and our changes disappear.

Any ideas why this is happening? Is this intended behaviour or a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, though it is a little subtle, and not guaranteed (just an implementation detail).

The callback to observe fires immediately when the command is inserted into `CommandQueue`. So the insert to `OtherCollection` happens while the `CommandQueue.insert` method is running, as part of the same call stack. This means the `OtherCollection` insert is considered part of the local 'simulation' of the `CommandQueue` insert, and is not sent to the server. The server runs the `CommandQueue` insert and sends the result back, at which point the client discards the results of the simulation and applies the results sent from the server, making the `OtherCollection` change disappear.

A better way to do this would be to write a custom method. Something like:

```
Meteor.methods({
  auditedCommand: function (command) {
    CommandQueue.insert(command);

    var whatever = someProcessing(command)
    OtherCollection.insert(whatever);
  }
});
```

Then:

```
Meteor.call('auditedCommand', command);
```

This will show up immediately on the client (latency compensation) and is more secure as clients can't insert to `CommandQueue` without also adding to `OtherCollection`.

**EDIT**: this will probably change. The added callback shouldn't really be considered part of the local simulation of CommandQueue.insert. Thats just the way it works now. That said, a custom method is probably still a better approach for this, it will work even if other people add commands to the command queue, and is more secure.

Comment: This solution worked fine as long as I had the 'insecure' package in my project. Removing it throws 'insert failed: Access denied' in OtherCollection.insert() on the client side. I obviously need the simulation to get good response time. But I can't give the client write access to OtherCollection as changes must be routed through audited transactions. Any idea how I could temporarily simulate the change in this case until the "real" change comes back from the server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your observe behavior but we accomplished the same thing using a server-side [allow](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) method:

```
CommandQueue.allow ({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    OtherCollection.insert(...);
    return (userId && doc.owner === userId);
  }
});
```

This is also more secure than putting this logic client side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm doing this client side because as it has direct influence on what the user sees on screen. So I want to avoid the latency of the connection (which is one of the big advantages of meteor, right)? I'm using the insecure package so security shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: ...and I admit that conceptually I'm not convinced that the allow() method is the right place to do data updates. It seems like a hack...