# Why is Meteor removing an object when observing a collection?

Tags: meteor

**Background**

- I have "Lists" and "Products" collections, Products belong to a List
- A List has a description, from which products are generated
- On startup, a new List is created that's unique for that visitor
- The List id is stored in the Session

**What I Want**

I want Products to be generated when the description of a List changes.

The first step is that when the list for the current visitor is changed, I want a new product to be inserted.

I get the feeling I'm going about this totally wrong...

**The Problem**

The product is inserted, appears in the browser for a split second, then vanishes. It's been removed by Meteor.

**Code**

```
Products = new Meteor.Collection("products");
Lists = new Meteor.Collection("lists");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var my_list_id = Lists.insert({description: "Default list"});
    Session.set("my_list", my_list_id);      

    var observed = Lists.find({_id: my_list_id}).observe({
      changed: function (newDocument, oldDocument) {
        Products.insert({list: newDocument._id, name: newDocument.description});
      }
    });
  });

  toggleElement = function (elementName) {
    if(editedElementIs(elementName)) {
      var newListDescription = $('textarea').val();
      Lists.update(Session.get("my_list"), {description: newListDescription});
      setEditedElement("");
    } else {
      setEditedElement(elementName);
    }
  };


  // Including the rest in case I've misunderstood something. 
  // I don't see how any of this could cause the issue.
  setEditedElement = function (elementName) {
    return Session.set("edited_element", elementName);
  };

  editedElementIs = function (elementName) {
    return Session.get("edited_element") == elementName;
  };

  Handlebars.registerHelper('editedElementIs', editedElementIs);

  Handlebars.registerHelper('products', function() {
    return Products.find({list: Session.get("my_list")});
  });

  Template.list_form.listDescription = function () {
    return Lists.findOne({_id: Session.get("my_list")}).description;
  };

  Template.adminbar.events({
    'click a#editlist' : function () {
      toggleElement("list");
    },
    'click a#editsidebar' : function () {
      toggleElement("sidebar");
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
  });
}
```

**What I've Tried**

Obviously, I can just do this:

```
if(editedElementIs(elementName)) {
  var newListDescription = $('textarea').val();
  Products.insert({list: Session.get("my_list"), name: newListDescription});
  Lists.update(Session.get("my_list"), {description: newListDescription});
  ...
```

But that's writing clumsy update code that I'd like to house in an observer.

It looked like the product was being removed. So I've observed when a product is removed thus:

```
Products.find({list:my_list_id}).observe({
  removed: function (oldDocument) {
    throw error("wow");
    console.log("Removed Product" + oldDocument);
  }
})
```

and this observer is called immediately after the Product is inserted.

I get the stack trace:

```
at Object.Products.find.observe.removed (http://localhost:3000/ListyMeteor.js?2d867b7481df6389658be864b54d864151e87da5:22:15)
    at Object.cursor.observeChanges.removed (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js?daa88dc39d67b40b11d6d6809d72361f9ef6a760:909:52)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js?daa88dc39d67b40b11d6d6809d72361f9ef6a760:275:15
    at _.extend.runTask (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor/fiber_stubs_client.js?52687e0196bc1d3184ae5ea434a8859275702d94:30:11)
    at _.extend.flush (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor/fiber_stubs_client.js?52687e0196bc1d3184ae5ea434a8859275702d94:58:10)
    at _.extend.drain (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor/fiber_stubs_client.js?52687e0196bc1d3184ae5ea434a8859275702d94:66:12)
    at LocalCollection.remove (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js?daa88dc39d67b40b11d6d6809d72361f9ef6a760:500:22)
    at Object.self._connection.registerStore.update (http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js?682caa185350aa26968d4ffc274579a33922f0e6:109:32)
    at Object.store.(anonymous function) [as update] (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata/livedata_connection.js?5d09753571656c685bb10c7970eebfbf23d35ef8:404:48)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata/livedata_connection.js?5d09753571656c685bb10c7970eebfbf23d35ef8:984:19
```

It looks like Meteor is flushing the Products collection on the client side.

I'm clearly misunderstanding how Meteor works.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

**Update 1**

It looks like this is happening because insert is being called within an observer:

[Why does meteor undo changes to collections nested in an observer method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250259/why-does-meteor-undo-changes-to-collections-nested-in-an-observer-method?rq=1)

I'll post back here once I confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Is autosubscribe turned on or off?

If you turn autosubscribe off, it could happen that your client updates the server copy and then on a subsequent update from the server - does not get all the items because its not subscribed to that collection.

Easiest way to check is to query the mongo db -

```
meteor mongo
```

Query the mongo db if your product has been added to the document.

If it has, then it is an autosubscribe issue -
You will have to create publish (on server) and subscribe (on client) methods as given here http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already checked this - no document has been added. It looks like it's added very briefly then deleted immediately...